# Черно-белое изображение в массив python

Tags: python, numpy, pil

Как я могу преобразовать черно-белое изображение в 1D массив, где 0 это черный, а белый это 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Совмещаем ответы из вопросов [Convert RGB to black OR white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777873/convert-rgb-to-black-or-white) и [Getting list of pixel values from PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109422/getting-list-of-pixel-values-from-pil). На входе не обязательно должно быть черно-белое изображение, можно использовать и цветное.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('1.png')
gray = img.convert('L')
bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<128 else 1, '1')
data = list(bw.getdata())  # Вместо list можно использовать другой тип данных
print(data)  # [1,0,0,1, ..... ]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)