# Png перевести в массив

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть картинка черно-белая. png. Могу ли я перевести её в массив где белые пиксели это 0, а чёрные это 1.
Хочу чтобы на выходе было, что то похожее.
Img = [0,1,1,0,
1,0,0,0,
1,1,0,0]
Возможно такое сделать?

Спасибо за ответ.
А как теперь из массива снова сделать рисунок.?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `with PIL.Image.open('bw.png') as im: img_list = list(im.tobytes())` ([Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow))

Comment: @Antonio, приложите к вопросу пример картинки...

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Черно-белое изображение в массив python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/992781/1365)

Comment: @MaxU а вообще в моей тестовой картинке можно [перевернуть палитру](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1PfJ.png) и тогда наивный tobytes тоже даёт неправильный результат, так что ваш вариант хоть и не доработан, но идеологически правильнее)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @andreymal, подожду пример картинки ;)

Comment: А как обратно, из массива в картинку перевести.

Comment: Белый фон и чёрный крест по середине. 410*410 пикселей.. Png формат. Вот и картинка